# How to find the sum of items and create new object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

How can i model an object similar to target object from following data?If there any shorthands exists in ES6, Then it would be more suitable.

The data sample contains the information of people and the items they  collected.The people Max and Carol has collected the same stones with different values.If this occurs, this should be pushed as a new item in our target object.

Sample data

```
let people = [{
  "id": 1,                        // Person Id
  "name": "John",                 // Name of person
  "date": "2017-5-27",            // Date
  "totalAssets": 500,             // Sum of total (gems collected)
  "gems": [{                      // Gems collected from forest
    "total": 500,           // totalCollected * value
    "value": 100,           // Value of one gem (Ruby = 100)
    "totalCollected": 5,    // Total number
    "gemName": "Ruby",      // Gem name
    "gemCode": "GEM001"     // Gem code
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Max",
  "date": "2017-5-28",
  "totalAssets": 1300, // TotalAssets = Emerald.total + Moonstone.total
  "gems": [{
    "total": 900,
    "value": 150,
    "totalCollected": 6,
    "gemName": "Emerald",
    "gemCode": "GEM002"
  }, {
    "total": 400,
    "value": 250,
    "totalCollected": 2,
    "gemName": "Moonstone",
    "gemCode": "GEM003"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Carol",
  "date": "2017-5-29",
  "totalAssets": 2900,
  "gems": [{
      "total": 1500,
      "value": 150,
      "totalCollected": 10,
      "gemName": "Emerald",
      "gemCode": "GEM002"
    }, {
      "total": 1000,
      "value": 200,
      "totalCollected": 5,
      "gemName": "Moonstone",
      "gemCode": "GEM003"
    },
    {
      "total": 400,
      "value": 100,
      "totalCollected": 4,
      "gemName": "Ruby",
      "gemCode": "GEM001"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Compute total

```
computeTotal = () => {   //Mock target object function
 // Return target object

   "totalAssets": 4800, //Total assets of all people
   "gemsValueTotal":[{
     "gemName": "Ruby",
     "value": 100,
     "totalC0llected":9,
     "total": 900,
   },
   {
     "gemName": "Emerald",
     "value": 150,
     "totalC0llected":16,
     "total": 2400,
   },
   {
     "gemName": "MoonStone",
     "value": 200,
     "totalC0llected":5,
     "total": 1000,
   },
   {
     "gemName": "MoonStone", // Value changed so push as new item in object
     "value": 250,
     "totalC0llected":2,
     "total": 500,
   }
   ]
}
```

I found some solution in this manner.

```
 aggregateGems(data) {
   this.rows = [];
   let totalCollected = 0;
   let totalvalue = 0;
   return data.filter((item) => {
       item.gems.map(d => {
        let model: any = {};
        let totalAssets: number = 0;
        totalCollected += parseInt(d.totalCollected);
        totalvalue += parseInt(d.total);
        model.gemname = d.gemName;
        model.value = d.value;
        model.totalCollected = totalCollected;
        model.totalValue = totalValue;
        this.rows.push(model);
        debugger
       });
     },
   );
 }
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @31piy Thanks for your response.Please check the updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) function, in cooperation with the [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ForEach?v=example) function.

```
// this will save the indexes of the gemNames and value in the output array (so you don't have to search for the index all of the time)
let gemNameValueIndex = {};
// this will reduce the people array in a new object, receiving the new object and the next person on each iteration
let totals = people.reduce( (current, person) => {

  // and for each person we need to iterate the gems
  person.gems.forEach( gem => {
    // each gem increases the total value
    current.totalAssets += gem.total;
    let key = gem.gemName + gem.value;
    let idx;
    if ((idx = gemNameValueIndex[key]) === undefined) {
      // no matching gem found, so add the index
      current.gemsValueTotal.push( { 
        gemName: gem.gemName,
        value: gem.value,
        totalCollected: gem.totalCollected,
        total: gem.total
      } );
      // mark the index so it can be looked up for next iterations
      gemNameValueIndex[key] = current.gemsValueTotal.length - 1;
      return;
    }
    // update the already found index with the new totals
    current.gemsValueTotal[idx].totalCollected += gem.totalCollected;
    current.gemsValueTotal[idx].total += gem.total;
  });

  return current;
}, { totalAssets: 0, gemsValueTotal: [] } );
```

Your `totals` object will now contain the data you were looking for (you can try it out in the snippet below).

The `gemNameValueIndex` will contain the gems per value as a key and the index in the resulting total object (but that object is only there to avoid looping all added gems in the gemsValueTotal to find the index based on gemName and value per gem that we need to compare)

```js
let people = [{
  "id": 1,                        // Person Id
  "name": "John",                 // Name of person
  "date": "2017-5-27",            // Date
  "totalAssets": 500,             // Sum of total (gems collected)
  "gems": [{                      // Gems collected from forest
    "total": 500,           // totalCollected * value
    "value": 100,           // Value of one gem (Ruby = 100)
    "totalCollected": 5,    // Total number
    "gemName": "Ruby",      // Gem name
    "gemCode": "GEM001"     // Gem code
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Max",
  "date": "2017-5-28",
  "totalAssets": 1300, // TotalAssets = Emerald.total + Moonstone.total
  "gems": [{
    "total": 900,
    "value": 150,
    "totalCollected": 6,
    "gemName": "Emerald",
    "gemCode": "GEM002"
  }, {
    "total": 400,
    "value": 250,
    "totalCollected": 2,
    "gemName": "Moonstone",
    "gemCode": "GEM003"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Carol",
  "date": "2017-5-29",
  "totalAssets": 2900,
  "gems": [{
      "total": 1500,
      "value": 150,
      "totalCollected": 10,
      "gemName": "Emerald",
      "gemCode": "GEM002"
    }, {
      "total": 1000,
      "value": 200,
      "totalCollected": 5,
      "gemName": "Moonstone",
      "gemCode": "GEM003"
    },
    {
      "total": 400,
      "value": 100,
      "totalCollected": 4,
      "gemName": "Ruby",
      "gemCode": "GEM001"
    }
  ]
}];

// this will save the indexes of the gemNames and value in the output array (so you don't have to search for the index all of the time)
let gemNameValueIndex = {};
// this will reduce the people array in a new object, receiving the new object and the next person on each iteration
let totals = people.reduce( (current, person) => {
  
  // and for each person we need to iterate the gems
  person.gems.forEach( gem => {
    // each gem increases the total value
    current.totalAssets += gem.total;
    let key = gem.gemName + gem.value;
    let idx;
    if ((idx = gemNameValueIndex[key]) === undefined) {
      // no matching gem found, so add the index
      current.gemsValueTotal.push( { 
        gemName: gem.gemName,
        value: gem.value,
        totalCollected: gem.totalCollected,
        total: gem.total
      } );
      // mark the index so it can be looked up for next iterations
      gemNameValueIndex[key] = current.gemsValueTotal.length - 1;
      return;
    }
    // update the already found index with the new totals
    current.gemsValueTotal[idx].totalCollected += gem.totalCollected;
    current.gemsValueTotal[idx].total += gem.total;
  });
  
  return current;
}, { totalAssets: 0, gemsValueTotal: [] } );

console.log( totals );
```

Comment: Thanks.This is exactly what I wanted.